# which is the best programming language suitable for sentimental analysis

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

it would be helpful if someone specify the best nlp libraries available

Comment: There is no programming language as such dedicated to sentiment analysis. Instead you have a number of languages which can use existing frameworks. For example UIMA, OpenNLP, Watson, etc.

Answer (score -1):

This is less to do with the programming language and more to do with what **APIs** are available for the particular language. Here's one for [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) and one for [Python](http://www.nltk.org/). You will need to do some research into which language out of many best suits your needs, no one here will be able to tell you which is most suitable. There are a lot of open source options and just as many proprietary ones.

Comment: ive tested nltk api using [link](http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/), but it is not that accurate.. It is showing negative polarity for Quoted/Indirect text like this -"My dad says this product is terrible, but I disagree" and positive polarity for missed negations  text like this- "I would never in a millions years say that this product is worth buying"